# How can I get user.id from a component in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to get user.id but i don't know how.

```
function App() {
  const users = 
  [
    {id: 1, name: "Gabriel", idade: 25},
    {id: 2, name: "Beatriz", idade: 26}
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((user) => 
      <div className='App'>
        <p>
          {user.id} {user.name} {user.idade}
        </p>
        <button onClick={console.log(user.id})>Clique aqui</button>
      </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I console.log(user.id) return all ids in Array.
Someone can help me ?

Comment: it's logging without you clicking isnt it?

Comment: This won't log anything to the console, this will produce syntax errors in the console: `onClick={console.log(user.id})`  When providing a [mcve] in the question, it's important to test that example and validate that it actually demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

[After correcting obvious typos and syntax errors in your code...]

This isn't doing what you think it does:

```
onClick={console.log(user.id)}
```

This executes `console.log(user.id)` *immediately* when rendering, and set the `onClick` handler to the *returned value* (which is `undefined`).  If you want to execute a function *on click* then you need to *provide a function to be called*, not just call a function:

```
onClick={() => console.log(user.id)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this. Your onClick function is wrong

```
  <button onClick={()=> console.log(user.id)}>Clique aqui</button>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-pond-2ssx83?file=/src/App.js:322-388

Answer (score 0):

**onClick** function takes a callback function so you have to write the code in this way:

```
<button onClick={() => console.log(user.id)}>Clique aqui</button>
```